# How to add custom timers to the performance debug page?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

On the performance page we see various metrics.

But it's *only* so useful when the grand majority of your work exists through the controller itself, and likely where you (the developer) are going to introduce bottle necks.

[image]

Is there a way to inject more custom timers into this page?

For example, this particular controller is unzipping and processing a zip archive.  I'd like to know visually how much of the controller execution length was taken to extract the archive, and how much was taken to process it.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html#timing-the-execution-of-the-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your zip controller extends Controller try:

```
use \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class zipController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $debugstopwatch = $this->get('debug.stopwatch');
        $debugstopwatch->start('zipController');


        /* ..  */

        $debugstopwatch->stop('zipController');

        /*render page*/

    }
}
```

Or inject \Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch

```
public function index(Request $request, \Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch $debugstopwatch)
{
    $debugstopwatch->start('zipController');

    /* ..  */

    $debugstopwatch->stop('zipController');



}
```

See [Stopwatch](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html)

Comment: You know, what I find strange, is I've tried this very thing for years and it just never worked (new metreics just wouldn't show up).  Even deep diving into the debug toolbar, replicating what I saw.. still nothing. So I'd sit here and write custom metrics for things.   And then bam, your answer, just doing it, now works!  Not sure why now vs before, but it does, and I thank you for helping me out!  Cheers!

Comment: @RedactedProfile You are welcome! Even I using $debug stopwatch = new Stopwatch() couldn't get it to work :-) I also find DataCollector (https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/data_collector.html) very useful for adding customized information!

Comment: I totally use custom Data Collector's all over the place for things like custom API metrics and data presentation, custom flagging and todo's, etc etc the debug toolbar is SO good